# Calculate conditional probability; throwing the cube

Tags: probability

The symmetrical cube was threw $30$ times.

Calculate probability situation, when in first $20$ throws came out $4$ times number $3$, if in $30$ throws number $3$ came out $7$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways can the result $(3)$ occur $7$ times in $30$ throws?
$$\binom{30}{7}$$
How many ways can the result $(3)$ occur $4$ times in the first $20$ throws?
$$\binom{20}{4}$$
How many ways can the result $(3)$ occur $3$ times in the remaining $10$ throws?
$$\binom{10}{3}$$
The first question defines your sample space. The other two define your event. The final solution is:
$$P=\frac{\binom{20}{4}\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{30}{7}}=\frac{323}{1131}\approx0.285588$$

Answer (score 0):

So in this case we are dealing with conditional probability, I think.

Let's calculate  $\mathbf{B}$

$7=7+0+0 \to $ $3$ times, because 7 could be anywhere

$7=6+1+0\to$ $6$ times

$7=5+1+1\to$ $3$ times

$7=5+2+0\to$ $6$ times

$7=4+3+0\to$ $6$ times

$7=4+2+1\to$ $6$ times

$7=3+2+2\to$ $3$ times

$7=3+1+3\to$ $3$ times

So

$\mathbf{B}=36$

Let's calculate $\mathbf{A} \cap\ \mathbf{B}$

$4=3+1\to$ $2$ times

$4=4+0\to$ $2$ times

$4=2+2\to$ $1$ time

$\mathbf{A} \cap\ \mathbf{B}=5$

So
$ P(\mathbf{A} \setminus \mathbf{B})=\left(\frac{5}{36}\right) $

Is it correct answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard method involves probabilities. $B$ is an event. It is not a probability, and even if it were, $36$ also is not a probability. Further, rolling “three” seven times in the first 10 rolls and not at all in the last 20 rolls is not nearly as likely as 4 times in the first 10 rolls, 3 times in the next 10, and 3 in the last 10, so if you were trying to define a sample space of several equally likely outcomes, this one does not work.